# How to Remove the selected index of a DropDownList?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.Net web for that inserts values into a database, I want to reset the selected items in the dropdownList, how do I do it properly?? I know with textBoxes I can use `TextBox1.Text = String.empty` but it doesnt seem to work with the dropdownLists

Comment: Please refer to [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please clear list  using below code . DropDownList1.Items.Clear();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `DropDownList` it would be better to first add an empty string at first position of the `DropDownList` by using `yourDropDownList.Items.Insert` method and then select it. Something like this:

```
yourDropDownList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(string.Empty, string.Empty));
yourDropDownList.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to clear all Items means you can use

```
aspDrop.Items.Clear(); // whill clear all the list items
```

If you want to change the selected index means you have to use

```
aspDrop.SelectedIndex = someIndex; // where index must be in the list
```

Or even you can use `.Insert()` method to insert an item to a particular index and make it as selected item.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want to clear dropdownList fully so you can clear it's items source such in this way:

```
ddItems.Clear();
```

But if you only want to clear selected dropdownListItem than S.Akbari solution:

```
ddItems.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(string.Empty, string.Empty));
ddItems.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess, everyone has given answers. But remember one thing to do as follows:

```
AppendDataBoundItems="False"
```

Set it to **false** as this will cause the rebound data to be appended to the existing list which will not be cleared prior to binding. The above is applicable when data is bound to the `DropDownList`. The rest will be done clearing it.